# Elements Hiding When Clicked document jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n6js3yem/1/)

Here i am hiding the buttons if `textarea` is empty and user clicks outside of `textarea`.
But when The `textarea` is empty and user clicks anyone of the buttons below the buttons should **NOT** Hide But run their respective functions .
Can anyone Help Me ?

Comment: Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n6js3yem/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `blur` event of `textarea`, added a check if button's parent div (`.tog`) is hovered, if yes, don't hide that.

**Updated Javascript:**

```
$('textarea').focus(function () {
    $('.tog').hide();
    $(this).siblings('.tog').show();
}).blur(function () {
    // check if hover is on buttons
    if ((!$(this).val().length > 0) && (!$(this).siblings('.tog').is(':hover'))) {
        $(this).siblings('.tog').hide();
    }
});

$('.upload').click(function () {
    alert('choose a file to upload');
});
$('.clear').click(function () {
    alert('cleared');
});
$('.save').click(function () {
    alert('saved');
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6js3yem/2/)**

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. code dumps aren't likely to help anyone but the OP.

Comment: I added comment "// Check if hover is on buttons". I think that is sufficient. Anything to suggest?

Comment: Yes, explicitly mention what was the issue and how your code below  fixes it, comments in code is an extra aid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but The little i understand is that you are looking for `event.stopPropagation();`. Used like this:

```
//apply a click event on the button
$('button').on('click',function(e){
//stop other event from firing when click on this
          e.stopPropagation();
//do you stuff with the button.....
});
```

This will stop other event from triggering when you click on, except it's own event!

Comment: For clarifications, please post in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Try This.
<script>
    var  c ;
 $('textarea').focus(function () {
    c = $(this).closest('.c');
    var a = $('#mytextid').val();
    if (a == '') {

    }
    else{
         c.children('.tog').show();
    }

}).keyup(function () {
    if(!$(this).val().length > 0){
    c = $(this).closest('.c');
    c.children('.tog').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        c.children('.tog').show();   
    }
});
$('.upload').click(function () {
alert('choose a file to upload');
});
$('.clear').click(function () {
alert('cleared');
});
$('.save').click(function () {
alert('saved');
});   

</script>

if this answer is complete your condition  so  please like.Thanks
```